# How to perform preprocessor check for if assembly references are included?

Tags: c#, com, .net-assembly, preprocessor-directive

Is it possible to perform a `#if` or `#ifdef` on something about/within an Assembly or COM reference?  For example:

```
#ifdef Microsoft.Office.Core
  //Create office object, etc.
#endif
```

Comment: You can't do that.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I've got the Office Interop integrated, but I'm having trouble with the WindowsAPICodePack.  So, I was trying to leave some scattered portions of code available, but uncompiled if I ever figured it out (without having to comment/uncomment).  For now, I have a "conditional compilation symbol", but I was just wondering if there was a simpler way.